# Where to ask this security-related question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I read on [How to ask a good question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the following text:

> If you're still unsure if you should ask your question on Information Security Stack Exchange, feel free to ask in our chat or on our meta site.

I want to ask a questions related to my security career, as I am just starting my masters on security, I am wondering which path to follow given some circumstances (I would prefer to freelance, etc). But I can't find a proper place on stack exchange community for an open-discussion like this.

Is this a proper discussion to open on security.stackexchange? If not, where could I ask it?

Comment: You are more than welcome to pop by in [chat] and ask!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We get a lot of these types of career questions.

Unfortunately, they are all far too opinion-based to be a good fit on the site. In addition, they tend to be hyper-specific to the individual and the context/locale.

We do have [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) that might fit your needs better.